# One to many relationship: not able to save

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to create a one to many relationship with some data I have.

I have a single `Project` and many items, I am trying to set up the controller to save them but this is the first time I have ever used a one to many relationship and my head is about to explode.

This is what my save method looks like

```
- (void)writeProj:(NSArray *)recivedProData ItemsData:(NSArray *)itemsData  {
    // WRITE TO CORE DATA
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];    

    for (NSDictionary *dict in recivedProData) {
    Project *project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];        

        project.projectNumber = [dict valueForKey:@"ProjectNumber"];
        project.projectDescription = [dict valueForKey:@"Description"];
//        project.items = [dict valueForKey:@""]; // this is the relationship for project        
    }

    for (NSDictionary *dict in itemsData) {
    Items *items = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        items.description = [dict valueForKey:@"Description"];
        items.area = [dict valueForKey:@"Area"];
        items.stage = [dict valueForKey:@"Stage"];
//        items.project = [dict valueForKey:@""]; // this is the relationship for items                 
    }    

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![__managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"There was an error! %@", error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"created");
    }

    [Project addItemsObject:items];

    [__managedObjectContext saveOnSuccess:^{

        NSLog(@"You created a relationship");

    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"There was an error! %@", error);

    }];        
}
```

So I have one `Project` and many `Items`, I just dont know how to set up the keyfields so that they save into core data as one project and many items.

So hopefully my code is making sense. If someone could just help me figure out how to save it properly that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set items.project to be equal to the project `NSManagedObject` you just made

```
items.project = project;
```

EDIT: if you have only one project, you should move the `Project* project` declaration outside of the `recivedProData` for loop -- you are making one project for every dictionary, and you say you only have one project ever. That entire block of code makes no sense if you have only one project though -- why do you have an array of `Project` data, and not just one dictionary?

Comment: okay. and then add the save into the items for loop.. this all makes logical sense.. let hope it works

Comment: I don't think you need to put the saveOnSuccess: call into a for loop -- it would be inefficient to save to the hard drive several times versus one time at the end like you have now (core data keeps your changes in memory until you close the app or discard them), and remember that flash memory on iOS devices only get a certain amount of writes before they wear out. Or did I completely misinterpret what you wrote?

Comment: sorry i wasnt too clear I was talking about this line of code [project addItemsObject:items]; not the save.. save is still outside the loop.. so i even need this code if i am  using your items.project = project;?

Comment: Which code? The saveOnSuccess:? If you want the data to persist after your users close the App you do need to keep it.

Comment: do you have any idea how you would read the projects and related items out into say an array?

Comment: Are you trying to do that so you can set the inverse of the relationship? Core Data does that for you, assuming your model is properly set up. When you call items.project = project, the item is added to the NSSet which represents the items associated with project. If you're trying to get all those objects for some other purpose, I suggest looking into NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate.

Comment: yep, thats exaclty what I am trying to do. i will mark your answer correct as it seems to have work. I have started another question regarding NSFetchRequest, which I know how to do for a single object but not two.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073531/fetch-coredata-relationship

thanks for your help.

Comment: just ready your edit.. it might sound naughty but i have never not used an array and because i know it works i was kinda just doing that for consistancy. lol .. ill update my code now.

Answer (score 0):

I want to discuss your Core Data model, the one you configured using the Core Data GUI editor. I'm curious about the plurality of the entity named "Items" from the following line of code:

```
Items *items = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Maybe it's just a matter of semantics. It's possible, however, that the plurality of that entity name indicates a problem in your Core Data model. I'll try to explain, but this is pretty abstract stuff.

Although an entity may have a relationship that represents a collection of things, the entity *itself* is not really a collection of things; the entity is always a single thing in the model and should be treated as such in your code (and in your naming schemes).

Here's how I would describe your model in words:
The Project entity is a single thing with a relationship called items. The items relationship is a collection (a set) of Item entities (i.e., a one-to-many relationship). But each Item entity is a single thing.

Does your model in the GUI editor reflect this description?

Comment: I think that explaines what I am doing. I have a Project which has many items.. items is a collection of item. dose that make sense? this is what I am trying to achive, I am pretty sure my data model is correct as I have a one to many relationship from project to items.. however I am just not sure my code reflects this as I have never attempted something like this before and I am relying on my experiance with writing and reading singular objects.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of just your data model from the GUI editor and post it? There are issues with the code you posted, as others have stated, but let's be certain that your model is correct first.